# Mapping problem when using Automapper in an Edit form with select list

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create an edit form which includes a selectlist that gets the data from the database. I am unable to display the form since I cannot map the viewmodel with the actual model using Automapper.

Contact.cs:

```
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string? EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public Company Company { get; set; }
```

ContactEditViewModel.cs:

```
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string? EMailAddress { get; set; }

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please select a company.")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public SelectList? Company { get; set; }
```

Edit View

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Company" class="control-label"></label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <select asp-for="CompanyId" class="form-select" asp-items="@Model.Company"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

ContactsController Edit Action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var contact = await _context.Contacts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ContactId == id);

            var model = new ContactEditVM
            {
                Company = new SelectList(_context.Companies, "CompanyId", "CompanyName"),
            };
            //var contact = mapper.Map<ContactEditVM>(await contactRepository.GetAsync(id));
            mapper.Map(model, contact);

            if (contact == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            //ViewData["CompanyId"] = new SelectList(_context.Companies, "CompanyId", "CompanyName", contact.Company);
            return View(model);
        }
```

MappingConfiguration

```
public class MapConfig : Profile
{
    public MapConfig()
    {
        CreateMap<Contact, ContactListVM>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Contact, ContactCreateVM>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Contact, ContactEditVM>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
SelectList -> Company
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList -> ENV.Data.Company

Destination Member:
Company

...

If I create a new instance of my viewmodel and assign values to it manually, without using Automapper, it works as intended. So what is wrong with my mapping?

Comment: I think the exception message tells you exactly what's wrong. How should AM map `SelectList` to `Company`?

Comment: You are right, exception message is clear. I get the problem but don't know how to deal with it. I am reading Automapper documentation right now.

Comment: Well, you probably don't have any mapping configuration in the mapping profile that tells AM how to map SelectList to Company. But you don't show your mappings.

Comment: Updated my post with current mapping profile. I don't have any custom modification there. How can I tell it to map a SelectList to a type? I tried to manually map them with ( .ForMember(m => m.Company, s=> s.MapFrom(src => src.Company)).ReverseMap(); )  but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: If I am not wrong, Company should be where the user gets to select a company from those that are in the database ?

Comment: @AchoVasilev yes, you are right.

Comment: @GertArnold If I rename the SelectList in the viewmodel, everything works. It fixes the issue but I still don't get the logic of it so I am not sure if this is a good workaround the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Does it work if you outcomment the "Company" from your Contact.cs and outcomment the "Company" from your ContactEditViewModel.cs?

I think you need to define a mapping which tells autoMapper how to map a "SelectedList?" to a "Company".

For Example:

```
        var autoMapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {

            cfg.CreateMap<WalletData/*Source*/, BP_WalletDTO/*Destination*/>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(src => src.Type))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Attributes, memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(src => new BP_WalletAttributesDTO
                {
                    CryptocoinId = src.Attributes.Cryptocoin_id,
                    CryptocoinSymbol = src.Attributes.Cryptocoin_symbol,
                    Balance = src.Attributes.Balance,
                    IsDefault = src.Attributes.Is_default,
                    Name = src.Attributes.Name,
                    PendingTransactionsCount = src.Attributes.Pending_transactions_count,
                    Deleted = src.Attributes.Deleted,
                    IsIndex = src.Attributes.Is_index,
                }));
        });
```

Maybe this helps

Comment: Tweaking with the mapping settings didn't work, got the same exception back. But since you asked if I outcomment the fields, if I just rename the field Company in the viewmodel, it works.